# Inserting Variable into Inline XML in VS2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, xelement, inline-xml

so i have some inline XML

```
Dim x As XElement = _
    <parent>
        <child></child>                    
    </parent>
```

what I want to do is get some variables that have been set into that xml

```
Dim v as string = "Blah"
Dim x As XElement = _
    <parent>
        <child>{v}</child>                    
    </parent>
```

Is this possible?  I am aware that I could make the whole thing one giant string and concatenate, or string.format.  But I want to know if this method is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, just as a guess, i tried using a <%= tag and it seems to have worked:

```
Dim v as string = "Blah"
Dim x As XElement = _
    <parent>
        <child><%= v %></child>                    
    </parent>
```

Comment: That syntax is meant to permit you to use LINQ expressions in there as well. See example at http://blogs.msdn.com/stcheng/archive/2008/03/05/asp-net-use-linq-to-xml-to-construct-xml-document-from-database-records.aspx.

Comment: yeah, i had no idea about this.  its very convenient, this way I don't have to go through and change every line of xml to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Xml.Linq namespace is very flexable, so yes you can
one way would be

```
Dim x As XElement = <test><One></One></test>
    x.FirstNode.ReplaceWith(<test2></test2>)

Output is <test><test2></test2></test>
```